# Best fitted distribution to my dataset?

Tags: r, distributions

I'd like to find best distribution to my data set below, and I have used (`fitdistrplus`) package but I do not know which distribution is fitted my data because my data set contains zeros. I used the commands below in R, but it does not work for most distributions, including the normal distribution.

Can anyone help me?

```
## Best fitted distribution

require(fitdistrplus)
require(logspline)

descdist(MR1, discrete=FALSE)

fit.norm <- fitdist(MR1, "normal")
plot(fit.norm)
```

My dataset:

(27
3.5
8.1
4.2
0.6
0
0
0
0
18.9
62.2
23.1
2.6
17
8.7
23.8
0.3
0
0
0
0
0
6.2
5.5
40
14.3
25.1
4.7
3.2
0
0
0
0
0
0.8
3.2
12.8
0.7
10.9
4.1
0.6
0
0
0
0
33
53.9
26.9
32.5
18.4
32.9
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
19.2
7.8
3.7
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
6
12.1
10
7
0.3
4.2
0
0
0
0
0
10.8
59.7
10
12.1
6.6
7
25.7
6
0
0
0
0
4
7.6
11.7
5
0.4
9.3
16
4
0
0
0
0
0.4
5.3
12.4
0
0
0.403
7.185
7.179
0
0
0
0
0.002
25.302
20.4
24.802
1.201
1.002
4.402
7.202
0
0
0
0
0.002
11.1
1.703
27.705
9.702
12.804
12.402
0.203
0
0
0
0
0.001
6.601
2.003
25.505
43.304
0.001
36.605
11.303
0
0
0
0
2.814
27.101
44.1
12.403
2.405
0.006
8.302
0.004
0
0
0
0
0.002
0.001
12.803
19.606
1.001
0.502
0.203
2.006
0
0
0
0
28.801
0.502
19.801
0.002
5.802
19.502
16.8
0.205
0
0
0
0
7.403
5.105
9.502
2.703
14.802
5.903
13.402
8.601
0
0
0
0
0
0
4.902
21.803
19.8
4.802
21.904
1.6
0
0
0
0
0.301
0.001
1.101
0.204
3.901
2.802
0.201
1.7
0
0
0
0
2.403
15.701
21.902
27.602
3.201
0.001
0.005
20.001
0
0
0
0
1.901
103.302
0.104
37.701
2.603
26.304
12.604
0.002
0
0
0
0
2.902
16.003
6.465)

Comment: This isn't clear. Why do you need to identify the distribution of these data anyway?

Comment: With a mix of discrete (the spike at 0) and (apparently) continuous, the usual laundry list of distributions would be useless. If you do come up with a plausible distribution with some few parameters, it will certainly be wrong (i.e. merely an approximation of the distribution) Why would you need to identify a distribution? (Actually, this problem looks slightly familiar -- is this an exercise for some class?) Can you say more about what is being measured here?

Comment: Thanks for your answer the measured data is rainfall and the purpose of distribution is part of time series analysis of   rain data for hydrological studies

Comment: Thanks for the information; it really should be in your question. I've added some information to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment the data is monthly rainfall from January 1994 to December 2014

Answer (score 1):

Taking the question at face value (i.e. leaving aside whether it's necessary or even advisable*), just looking at the numbers without knowing what they are (which is were a model *should* start -- from an understanding of the thing being measured) there are obviously zeroes in the data but the rest of it seems positive and continuous.

* throwing a laundry list of distributions at a problem without accounting for the overfitting (etc) that this approach leads to would be inviting a host of problems.

An obvious place to start would be a mix of a spike at 0 and a positive continuous distribution, of which there are very large numbers. If we just try one (my first thought was a gamma, for no especially good reason since I'm operating in ignorance of what we're measuring here), fitting a gamma to the non-zero part seems to give a perfectly plausible approximation to the distribution:

[image]

In response to the additional information relating to rainfall -- this would be a  mixture of *different* distributions. If we have 252 days of rainfall, that covers several seasons, and one part of the year would be expected to have different rainfall patterns than others. As such - even if rainfall patterns were stable from year to year - this marginal distribution would depend on which 252 days were included and so still wouldn't be useful in telling us about the rainfall overall, nor in any particular part of the year (like a given month).

I have seen lognormal distributions used for the *conditional* distribution of rainfall (e.g. given there was some rain, and given the time of year, and given whether or not there was rain on the previous day); that might well be adequate to model your data. Alternatively a conditional gamma or Weibull might work well enough in the same circumstances.

However, I fail to see how just smooshing the conditional distributions all together is likely to be useful at all.